# Multiple html div's using same css style

Tags: css

I have 2 div elements #container1 , #container2. Can i use styling in below manner ?

```
#container1,#container2 h5{ 
}
```

If yes then i cudn't get it to work for #container3

```
#container1,#container2,#container3 h5{ 
}
```

rule somehow doesn't seem to apply for #container3 ..
What could be the reason ?

Comment: Why do you have a stray `h5` at the end of your selector? Are you trying to apply styles to `h5` within any of those elements?

Comment: Can you push some more code like styling & html

Comment: why not put a different ID for all div and then have same class name for all??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That selector will apply to #container1,#container2, and any h5s in #container3. I think you want:

```
#container1 h5, 
#container2 h5, 
#container3 h5 {
  /* styling */
}
```

This is exactly what classes are intended for, however. If you add `class="container"` to each of your container `div`s, you can simply use the following rule:

```
.container h5 {
  /* styling */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The h5 at the end means that particular rule only applies to h5 elements inside the id.

As an exmaple, from your first example...

```
#container1,#container2 h5{ 
}
```

The above rules would apply to an element with id=contrainer1 and also to an h5 element inside an element with id=container2.

With:

```
#container1,#container2,#container3 h5{ 
}
```

You are actually targetting id=container1, id=container2 and also the h5 element inside an element with id=container3

In both cases though, the element with the h5 tag does not target the element itself, only the heading tag inside it.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to correct but you can use another solution...
why you doesnt use calss for every div you want?

```
.divcontainer{
css....
}
```

Comment: in your css you use h5 for container3
and the class you define only effect for h5 inside container3