# Add the same style to several ids

Tags: css

I have a `.css` file and I apply the same style to many objects :

```
#tab_traitement
{
    visibility : hidden;
}
#tab_bloc
{
    visibility : hidden;
}
#tab_pe
{
    visibility : hidden;
}

#tab_stationClimatique
{
    visibility : hidden;
}

#tab_itk
{
    visibility : hidden;
}

/*... and others !*/
```

I want something to apply a style to all of these elements and avoid repetition.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Those aren't classes...they are IDs.

Comment: all these id's are under in one parent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple html div's using same css style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562155/multiple-html-divs-using-same-css-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 #tab_traitement, #tab_bloc, #tab_pe, ,#tab_stationClimatique, #tab_itk

 {
   visibility : hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's what I need :)

Answer (score 2):

Move that style instead to a new css class and use it in your HTML markup:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And then in your html simply use the class instead of relying on the "id":

```
<div id="tab_itk" class="hidden"> ... </div>
```

Comment: @BenMansley Why ? The other solution works too. Is this solution more usual or better ?

Comment: @Erlaunis For this specific situation either solution will work. If you ever end up needing to conditionally apply this CSS (e.g., based on what tab is selected) then you can use javascript to add/remove CSS classes easily. This may not be as easy to do when you're "hard coding" your styling based on the IDs of the HTML elements.

Comment: @SamStorie Ok, in my case I use javascript to change the css of specific elements, so your solution will be hard to make. Moreover, I already have a class specific to a framework that I use. But thank you for your answer :)